# Error in the output of a chat app - Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am following a MVA course and the objective of the module is to built a Chat App using Angular JS. When the instructor ran the code the output was as expected.

**Expected Output:**
When the name and message are entered in the input field, the output should display the name and message entered in the above input field and also the time when they entered the data once the button is clicked.

The following is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chirp</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/chirpApp.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="chirpApp">
    <div id='main' class="container" ng-controller="mainController">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
        <div class="clearfix">
          <form ng-Submit="post()">
            <input required type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" ng-model="newPost.created_by" /> 
            <textarea required class="form-control" maxlength="200" rows="3" placeholder="Say something" ng-model="newPost.text"></textarea>
            <input class="btn submit-btn pull-right" type="submit" value="Chirp!" />
          </form>
          <div id="post-stream">
            <h4>Chirp Feed</h4>
                <div class="post" ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'created_at':true" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'"> 
                  <p>{{post.text}}</p>
                <small>Posted by @{{post.created_by}}</small>
                <small class="pull-right">{{post.created_at | date:"h:mma 'on' MMM d, y"}}</small>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var app = angular.module('chirpApp', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope){
  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};

  $scope.post = function(){
    $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();
    $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost);
    $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};
  };
});
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    padding-top:70px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

a {
    color: #00B7FF;
}

.submit-btn {
    background-color: #b1dbff;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.post {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.odd {
    background-color: #f2f9ff;

}
.even {
    background-color: #eceff3;
}

.form-auth {
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

*The code is available on their github account from which I copy pasted it, so I don't think it's a problem with the code.*

When I open the page, the following gets displayed:

> {{post.text}} Posted by @{{post.created_by}} {{post.created_at | date:"h:mma 'on' MMM d, y"}}

which is not the desired output.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I just created a Plunk with your exact code and it is working as you expect it to. See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/dUfsEviT21tq70O0bmJm?p=preview

Comment: `ng-Submit` should be `ng-submit`. Always use lowercase for directive attributes in markup

Comment: @Yerken: When I open the page, the following gets displayed:
{{post.text}}

Posted by @{{post.created_by}} {{post.created_at | date:"h:mma 'on' MMM d, y"}}

Comment: When I enter the data, the page simply gets refreshed and nothing shows in the output except the above text

Comment: @JordanMcRae: Yeah, that's what it should do. But it still doesn't work on my machine though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first when I tried copy pasting the code into my own environment it didn't work. After looking through I realized that the references to the javascript and css files were trying to look in folders that did not exist. Since I created one project folder and put all three files in it, my references are as follows:

```
Change
<script src="javascripts/chirpApp.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">

To
<script src="chirpApp.js"></script>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

After fixing both of these, it works perfectly fine. Make sure that if you're copying the code, you have the same file names and folder structure or else the references you are copying will not work.

Comment: I had the folders created however, now I have put all the files in one folder and it works just fine. Also, there was a typo in my .js file at the module. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

The output on the page indicates that the `posts` array is empty. This is because no data was submitted by the form as a result of a typo in the `ng-submit` directive. You should refactor this line in the HTML file:

```
<form ng-Submit="post()">
```

to this:

```
<form ng-submit="post()">
```

This would register the `ng-submit` directive and enable the form submit data.

Comment: Done but, no luck yet.

Comment: What's the output now?

Comment: The page still loads with {{post.text}} Posted by @{{post.created_by}} {{post.created_at | date:"h:mma 'on' MMM d, y"}}. Just can't understand why.

Comment: do you have a local web server set up? How are you testing the code?